# Checking my IPTables Ports, modify through /etc/services?

Tags: iptables

I just flushed my IPTables ruleset and I'm writing new rules.  I'm going to keep it pretty simple.  I'm basically denying any IPs for INPUT that isn't the 1 i'm using, then I'm going to open port 80, 443, and the port for PLESK.  That's it.

When I `iptables -L -v`, it doesn't show the actual ports.  It seems it gives names based on the list configured in /etc/services, so do I need to update this list if I moved PLESK to a different port and it will update the name accordingly? For the sake of keeping track (in case I write more rules) I'd like to at least see the name of the service I'm making a rule for when I check it.

For example, I moved my SSH port, but if I write a rule stating if that port is attempted more than 4 times in a minute, it will REJECT the IP, I want it to actually say `ssh` in my IPTables ruleset, not `dpt:pc-telecommute` or whatever the generic is.

So updating /etc/services does this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-n` with `iptables` to not map IPs or ports to names.

Don't change `/etc/services`. Really.

Comment: ....errrrp.... well I did.... haha, Lemme get right on changing that back... thanks for the tip though, that works great too!

Comment: If you want to see a bit more detail with rules when running `iptables -nvL` then create each rule using the `comment` match extension.

Comment: so, I'm assuming I don't want to touch /etc/services because that's the name identified when starting/restarting/stopping any service?  22 I returned back to ssh (even though the Port has moved) but I did retitle my port using PLESK to PLESK.  Does that mean my command `/etc/init.d/psa` commands will stop working?

Comment: `/etc/services` is distributed by your operating system vendor so it _may_ be over-written in OS updates. It lists standard services as assigned by IANA. You shouldn't change the IANA-supplied services. You may add your own custom ones, but similarly they may get over-written.

Comment: ah.  well at least I know to go to IANA to get that list back to it's original state.  I only changed 2 things.  Many thanks to both of you.